# Sum of values not working (matrix table in Power BI)

Tags: matrix, sum, powerbi-desktop

I have a matrix and have added 'Dates[Weekending] as Columns (filtered by next 12 weeks).  However, when i add the Remaining Hours field in the Values area and select Sum, the result is incorrect.  It should be 51302 for 5/7/23 but is coming as 182544.  The sum of budgeted hours appears correct.

DatesTable - containts dates column and weekending column

Schedule Raw Data - Unique field is activity id.  it contains budgeted hours, actual hours and remaining hours but not by specific weekending.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25JgF.png)

Budgeted Hours = activity Id is related to activity id in Raw schedule.  Date is related to Date in Weekending table.  This table contains budgeted hours for the specific week and specific activity id.  the dates in this table were originally in columns.  So, they have been unpivoted.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJXcR.png)

Remaining hours table - activity id related to activity id in raw data and dates tied to dates in weekending.  this table contains remaining (scheduled) hours for the specific date by activity id.  the dates in this table were originally in columns.  So, they have been unpivoted.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm5cM.png)

this should be simple.  Just place the Remaining Hours field in the rows and select Sum.

I have tried using the Dates field from the Remaining Hours table.  The result is less than it should be (24315).

I have tried using a measure (Remaining Hours = SUM('Remaining Units by ACTNO'[Remaining Early Hours])).  results are identical to just using the regular sum on the value.